# how to get my layout to be at the bottom of my activity

Tags: android, xml

hello I am working on a ios styled app that has a layout out the bottom well I can't seem to get this layout in question to be at the bottom

here's my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    tools:ignore="UselessLeaf,ContentDescription" >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:padding="3dp" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/dock"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dial"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:src="@drawable/dialer"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:src="@drawable/back" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sms"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:src="@drawable/mms" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/music"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/music"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

here's what it looks like right now:
[IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0GHlGFNk1eSaDEtRGI5R0ZKYWM/view?usp=sharing)

I want the buttons at the bottom of the page

what am I doing wrong?

please let me know

thanks a million times over

Chris

Comment: "I am working on a ios styled app" Please, stop working right now and refuse to proceed until you have an "Android style" to work with. Android users will kind of punish you for an iOS app lookalike in the store...

Answer (score 1):

As Hesam's answer pointed out when you use the `layout_weight` attribute in your 2nd layout you should make the `layout_height=0dp`...if you're using Android Studio then it should be giving you a warning about it. However, I'd like to add to his answer that there's a lot of room for improvement in your layout file as a whole...and I mean A LOT!!! You've got what I call a spaguetti of useless nested layouts. To mention a few

1. The 2nd `LinearLayout` is absolutely useless...it's empty, not needed
2. The root `LinearLayout` can be easily converted to a `RelativeLayout`, then push the bottom-most child view to the bottom using `layout_alignParentBottom=true` and finally stack all other children on top of this bottom view using `layout_above`
3. You have a lot nested `LinearLayout` with one single child...IMHO this is useless
4. You have a lot nested `RelativeLayout` with one single child...IMHO this is useless as well

I could go on forever, but you really should address these nested layout issues because you are adding a lot of unnecessary overhead to your UI...this is pretty heavy man

#### Further recommendations based on the screenshot added

This what I would recommend

- I'd recommend using a `RelativeLayout` as the root/top layout
- Add a `ListView` to display all those images/icons and set the `layout_alignParentTop=true` with `layout_height=wrap_content`
- Then add a `LinearLayout` below it with a horizontal orientation to display the buttons

Comment: thanks for the reply I edited the code and I'm still getting the same issue can you look at the new code and see what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @appd3vs sorry mate but I'm gonna vote to close this question...you are technically asking to re-write the entire layout for you...this crazy because there are way too many issues in your layout

Answer (score 0):

When you are using android:layout_weight="1" then wither of android:layout_width or android:layout_height should be equal to 0dp. In your case second linear layout should be android:layout_height="0dp"

Comment: actually I'd prefer to say that the second layout is absolutely useless

Comment: #Leo explained completely. If you have nothing in you LinearLayouts then just remove them from your code as he explained. If I was you I used Relativelayout based on what #Carsten and #Leo say.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RelativeLayout as parent and then use alignParentBottom=“true” however I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve i.e. how it should look like.

Comment: guys thanks for the reply I edited the code and I'm still getting the same issue can you look at the new code and see what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as a root layout and then set     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the bottom layout